# Error with varargs for function-objects in Scala?

Tags: scala, syntax, variadic-functions

Why does this not work?

```
val f = (args: Int*) => args.sum

error: ')' expected but identifier found.
val f = (args: Int*) => args.sum
                  ^
```

This however works perfectly fine

```
def sum(args: Int*) = args.sum
val f = sum _
```

so does this

```
val f: (Int*) => Int = args => args.sum
```

btw. I'm using scala 2.9.1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm not an expert in specification reading, but it looks like the varargs Syntax is not supported for anonymous function.

Compare the syntax for Function Declaration vs Anonymous Functions in the [Language Spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)

### From 4.6 Function Declarations and Definitions

```
ParamType ::= Type
              | ‘=>’ Type
              | Type ‘*’
```

### 6.23 Anonymous Functions

```
Binding ::= (id | ‘_’) [‘:’ Type]
```

I have no idea what the reasons for that though. There seem to be reasons but none that can easily be explained. Martin Odersky commented on a request to add varargs for anonymous functions: "This looks tempting at first, but it would drag in a lot of complexity (you just need to believe me on that one)."

Comment: "This looks tempting at first, but it would drag in a lot of complexity" says the language creator. See https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3652

Answer (score 3):

There's also a good explanation on this given by Lex Spoon here [here](http://blogs.tedneward.com/CommentView,guid,c402d616-1ac3-4462-bc56-e88a657b59c0.aspx#commentstart)

> The syntax is a little misleading here; perhaps it is being too cute. The Any* syntax for varargs makes it look like Any* is itself a type. Really, the * is an annotation on the method parameter, not on the type.
>
> When you write down a function type using the T1=>T2 syntax, both T1 and T2 need to be plain old bona fide types. Scala provides oodles of kinds of types, but vararg types are not one of them.
>
> In practical code, the way out is to explicitly use a sequence type. In fact, if you look at the inferred type for good2, you will see it involves Seq[Any] rather than Any*.